# How to split contents in a single column into two separate columns in R?

Tags: regex, r, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe:

```
Colname
20151102
19920311
20130204
>=70
60-69
20-29
```

I wish to split this column into two columns like:

```
Col1         Col2
20151102
19920311
20130204
            >=70
            60-69
            20-29
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Try `do.call(cbind, split(df, cumsum(grepl('>', df$Colname))))` if you want as two separate columns.

Comment: @akrun I like that one. Should post it

Comment: @DavidArenburg But, it seems that is not the OP wanted :-)

Comment: Or an option to get the desired result would be `indx <-  cumsum(grepl('>', df$Colname));
df1 <- data.frame(Col1=df$Colname, Col2=df$Colname, stringsAsFactors=FALSE);
 df1[!indx,1] <- '';
 df1[indx,2] <- ''`

Comment: The column can also have data placed arbitarily. >=70 can be the 2nd entry of the column!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the need of any package:

```
df[,c("Col1", "Col2")] <- ""

isnum <- suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(df$colname)))

df$Col1[isnum] <- df$colname[isnum]
df$Col2[!isnum] <- df$colname[!isnum]

df <- df[,!(names(df) %in% "colname")]
```

Data:

```
df = data.frame(colname=c("20151102","19920311","20130204",">=70","60-69","20-29"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: this approach is not yeilding results.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to precise `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` when I created the data-frame. Now that works.

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution, the idea is to use `extract` from `tidyr`. Note that the delimiter I choose (the dot) must not appear in your initial `data.frame`.

```
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)

df$colname = df$colname %>% 
             grepl("[>=|-]+", .) %>% 
             ifelse(paste0(".", df$colname), paste0(df$colname, ".")) 

extract(df, colname, c("col1","col2"), "(.*)\\.(.*)")
#     col1  col2
#1  222222      
#2 1111111      
#3          >=70
#4         60-69
#5         20-29
```

**Data:**

```
df = data.frame(colname=c("222222","1111111",">=70","60-69","20-29"))
```

Comment: You should swap the `library()` calls otherwise your code won't work because `tidyr::extract` is masked by `magrittr:extract`

Comment: This approach looks promising and might work, but I am unable to use tidyr.

Comment: The error messsage says "Error in library(tidyr) : there is no package called ‘tidyr’"

Comment: maybe you need first install.packages("tidyr") ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single statement solution.  `read.pattern` captures the two field types separately in the parts of the regular expression surrounded by parentheses.  (`format` can be omitted if the `Colname` column is already of class `"character"`.  Also, if it were desired to have the first column numeric then omit the `colClasses` argument.)

```
library(gsubfn)
read.pattern(text = format(DF$Colname), pattern = "(^\\d+$)|(.*)", 
                   col.names = c("Col1", "Col2"), colClasses = "character")
```

giving:

```
      col1     col2
1 20151102         
2 19920311         
3 20130204         
4          >=70    
5          60-69   
6          20-29
```

**Note:** Here is a visualization of the regular expression used:

```
(^\d+$)|(.*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/YNgkGoF5mM1Ur0mE)